# Invoke method using Reflection on COM Object

Tags: c#, reflection, com

I have an instance of a COM object... which is created like this:

```
Type type = TypeDelegator.GetTypeFromProgID("Broker.Application");
Object application = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

When I try to invoke a method:

```
type.GetMethod("RefreshAll").Invoke(application, null);
```

-> `type.GetMethod("RefreshAll")` returns `null`. 
When I try to get all the methods with `type.GetMethods()`, there is only these methods:

1. GetLifetimeService
2. InitializeLifetimeService
3. CreateObjRef
4. ToString
5. Equals
6. GetHashCode
7. GetType

Where is the RefreshAll Method? And how can I invoke it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use GetMethod on COM objects, you have to use a different 
way:

```
this.application.GetType().InvokeMember("RefreshAll", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, this.application, null);
```

I am using this way in a old project that uses COM so it should work ok for you.

Comment: Though a fine answer at the time, c# 4 makes it much easier to perform COM-interop via the `dynamic` keyword below

Comment: Attention, coming from using `dynamic` in my tool https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ I discovered heavy memory leaks with it. I switched to the answer from Nathan W to fix that! See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080252/memory-overflow-having-an-increasing-number-of-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-s/34123315

Comment: See the other comments on MickyD's answer on how to deal with the issue ...

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is a late answer but c# 4 changes things a bit with the introduction of the `dynamic` keyword which was designed with COM-interop in mind.

MSDN:

> The COM interop scenario that the C# team specifically targeted in the C# 4 release was programming against Microsoft Office applications, such as Word and Excel. The intent was to make this task as easy and natural in C# as it always was in Visual Basic. [1]

Your code now becomes:

```
Type type = TypeDelegator.GetTypeFromProgID("Broker.Application");
dynamic application = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
application.RefreshAll(); // <---- new in c# 4
```

Now you won't see `RefreshAll()` in Visual Studio statement completion so don't be alarmed.  It will compile.

[1] [Understanding the Dynamic Keyword in C# 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx)

Comment: Attention, coming from using `dynamic` in my tool https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ I discovered heavy memory leaks with it. I switched to the answer from Nathan W to fix that! See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080252/memory-overflow-having-an-increasing-number-of-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-s/34123315

Comment: @Waescher odd considering MS made it for COM in the first place.  I suspect you are just not releasing things properly which has nothing to do with **dynamic**

Comment: @Waescher ooh I just did some googling and it appears you are correct.  Nasty little **dynamic**.   Good find

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That link I posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080252/memory-overflow-having-an-increasing-number-of-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-s/34123315) shows *exactly* the problem I face as well, with all the RuntimeBinder stuff. And don't get that wrong, that leak is huge: http://i.imgur.com/5ucIcI6.png. I might add that I call that method containing the `dynamic` quite often but anyways ...

Comment: @Waescher No, thank-_you_.   I guess I wasn't noticing it in my stuff as the apps don't run for very long then exit.   Hopefully MS will rectify. :)

Comment: I wrote a little helper class to deal with COM objects for my project here: https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ/blob/master/RepoZ.Api.Win/PInvoke/Combridge.cs. This one makes sure that COMs are released properly and methods and properties can be accessed without the use of `dynamic`. Here's how it is intended to be used: https://github.com/awaescher/RepoZ/blob/master/RepoZ.Api.Win/PInvoke/Explorer/ExplorerWindowActor.cs

Comment: Added that information in more detail to another SO question. If interested, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45827735/704281

Comment: This dynamic example doesnt work for COM classes in my project. It says It cant find the methods and properties

Comment: @CodeTruthSeeker consider posting that as a _new question._