# Calling method from COM Object using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, com

In order to allow compatibility with another project that is written in .Net 2.0, we have had to come up with a COM interop (the newer application is in .Net 4.0). This would work because the 2.0 process would be able to use SxS execution with .Net 4.0. In order to have a COM interop from what I understand I have to do something like this:

```
Type myClass = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Net4Assembly.Assembly4");
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClass);
IAssembly4 assembly4Interface = (IAssembly4)myInstance;
assembly4Interface.CallMethod();
```

I have already created the COM component and registered it and this works fine. But the problem is that since the project written in 2.0 is outside our department, I want to find a way of doing the casting in line 3 above using reflection. So far I have found a suggestion in [Invoke method using Reflection on COM Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773022/invoke-method-using-reflection-on-com-object)

But this doesn't work for me since when I get all the methods of the object in "myInstance" which is of type COMObject, I can only see the methods that are mentioned in that link. I get this error:

> Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

I think I should somehow cast the `COMObject` to the interface and then I would have access to the methods? Shouldn't I be able to extract the interface from the `COMObject`, then call the method using reflection? I tried `GetInterfaces(`) from the `COMObject` but nothing is returned.

Comment: will that code work `using system.Runttime.InteropServices` in the header..? Most common problem for this `Error` is because you have `a Misspelling in the Assembly Name` that you are trying to `Invoke`

Comment: I am not sure whether it would work but I would try this `dynamic myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClass); myInstance.CallMethod();`

Comment: Yes that's the first things I checked. The assembly name should be correct since I'm already able to call CallMethod() if I cast it to the IAssembly4 interface. I have also double checked the name of the method I'm calling(CallMethod()) using Reflection and that is correct too. I also don't get as mentioned in the link, why InvokeMember and InvokeMethod are different in this case?

Comment: @I4V: Unfortunately the project that has this code is using .Net 2.0 and hence no dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work but assuming you have `No Misspelled Assembly Name` try something like this

```
Type myClass  = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Net4Assembly.Assembly4");
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClass );
//object[] arguments = new object[] //add parameters if youre assembly expects them here
object result = myClass .InvokeMember("SubtractTwoNumbers", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
     null, myInstance, arguments);
```

Comment: have you verified that the Assembly name is correct make sure the casing is exact.. I am not sure why it's not working then..this is just another way of doing what you are trying to accomplish.. `I would start simple` for example double check the name of the `assembly` if you have to `Hit F2` on the file name and copy paste it into your code that way you don't  have to worry about typo's

Comment: As it turns out the problem was with the way I had defined the method in the interface. I had used explicit implementation which would cause the method to be not public? I used BindingFlags.NonPublic too and still couldn't reach the method ! Anyways...It is working now. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Awesome. I am extremely happy that I was able to help I was looking at this from how I would have done things back in my `Delphi` days and doing the attempted `C# conversion` awesome I guess I have led you to the `Golden Path` two thumbs up `Farhad`